# What is the goal of Meditation- is it increasing the gap?

Tags: meditation-practicalities, meditation-recommendation, meditation-effects

When I sit for meditation, sometimes I realize my breath has stopped and thoughts are subtle, for but a very minimum amount of time, but that time I feel totally in a present moment, in a moment.

It this a goal of meditation? or something else? or analyzing? When is the awareness aware of awareness? Is feeling the gap awareness?

Comment: Do you have a specific method of meditation?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Source: [Anapanasati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapanasati)

If you see step 4 above it says "Tranquilise the bodily activities". In this stage you do calm the breath, i.e., increase the gap, but you do not manipulate the breath directly.

For further reference on claiming the breath see: [LECTURE THREE: CALMING THE KAYA](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm#LECTURE%20THREE) from [ANAPANASATI - MINDFULNESS WITH BREATHING Unveiling the Secrets of Life: a Manual for Serious Beginners](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books3/Bhikkhu_Buddhadasa_Anapanasati_Mindfulness_with_Breathing.htm) by [BUDDHADASA BHIKKHU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhadasa), [Knowing and Seeing](http://www.dhammatalks.net/Books13/Pa-Auk-Sayadaw_Knowing-and-Seeing-4th-Ed-2010.pdf) 4th Ed. by [Ven. Pa-Auk Sayadaw](http://www.paaukforestmonastery.org/abbot.htm) p35.

Also in meditation you have to be in the present moment and see arising and passing or sensation at the present moment as you have realise.

Comment: Is the experiencing rapture referring to the same rapture as one of the ten imperfections of insight ?

Comment: @Ryan I think that the 10 imperfections are experiences that we can get stuck on, which could block progress. Like anything else that we experience, they are a sign of something or other, and we should note and move on. Rapture is a sign of a particular stage of meditative attainment, and we need to continue on past that. This is like something that my Meditation Teacher told me. So, I can't say it is the same or different - rapture is rapture - but your attitude towards it matters.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons why people meditate, who should know what your intent is. As for the path of Dhamma, its to get insight, knowledge and vision: pañña. And it's purpose is to get ride of dukkha (suffering and stress).

It's pretty good to ask one self why do I meditate or better, why I still don't do it. Atma does not know where Ajay actually stand and where his/her general thought about it come from, but a good guide in simple words would be [Buddho](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/thai/thate/buddho.html).

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Answer (score 2):

- Goal Of Meditation

The **Goal of Meditation** is being in the **PRESENT MOMENT**. Why? Because Past and Future does not exist. They exist only in the mind. What really exist is a Present moment, and what we really have is a Present Moment.

Answer (score 0):

Meditation leads to silence (here-now) which leads to Nirvana. Therefore if you talk about goal then probably it is Nirvana. But you cannot aim for it in a direct way. You cannot work for it. It will come on its own.